# how can I set multi xticks, with multi-angle rotations with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show x_label_1 and x_label_2 in my fig just like the sample image, with x_label_1 of no rotation and  x_label_2 under x_label_1, and x_label_2 rotated by 70 degree

[image]

and here is my code：

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

    def jinDrawPragnogram2021013002():

        x = list(range(1,11))
        data_augment = [ 0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7.5, 8, 10, 11, 10.5]
        data_upperlimit = [1.5, 2.5, 4.5, 7.5, 10, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13]
        data_mean = [2.1, 3.78, 6.3, 8.4, 9.24, 9.66, 10.08, 10.5, 10.92]
        x_label_1 = ['16+2', '18+4', '22+6', '28+6',    '33+1', '35+1', '36+0',  
            '37+2', '38+4', '39+1']
        x_label_2 = ['2019/6/10', '2019/6/26', '2019/7/26', '2019/9/6',  \
            '2019/10/6', '2019/10/20', '2019/10/26', '2019/11/4', \
            '2019/11/13',   '2019/11/17']

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        ax.plot(x, data_augment)
        ax.xticks(x, x_label_1, rotation='horizontal')
        #plt.plot(x, data_augment)
        plt.xticks(x, x_label_2, rotation=70)
        plt.show()

        return

    if __name__=='__main__':
        jinDrawPragnogram2021013002()
```

Comment: What did you try? How does your data look like (not as image, but as text)? Do you have some minimal reproducible example code?  With matplotlib you can easily draw lines and add text in the region of the xticks.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I have add some details about my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ax.text` to add text and `ax.plot` to draw the vertical dividers. With [`get_xaxis_transform()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-advanced-transforms-tutorial-py), the `x` can be entered as "data coordinate" and the `y` as "axis coordinate". The exact distance needed depends on the vertical text, its font and the size of the plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(range(1, 11))
data_augment = [0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7.5, 8, 10, 11, 10.5]
x_label_1 = ['16+2', '18+4', '22+6', '28+6', '33+1', '35+1', '36+0', '37+2', '38+4', '39+1']
x_label_2 = ['2019/6/10', '2019/6/26', '2019/7/26', '2019/9/6', '2019/10/6', '2019/10/20', '2019/10/26', '2019/11/4', '2019/11/13', '2019/11/17']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, data_augment)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label_2, rotation='vertical')
dist = -0.35
for xi, labeli in zip(x, x_label_1):
    ax.text(xi, dist, labeli, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), ha='center', va='bottom')
for xi in x + [x[-1] + 1]:
    ax.plot([xi - 0.5, xi - 0.5], [0, dist], color='black', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0) # hide x tick markers
ax.set_xlim(x[0]-0.5, x[-1]+0.5)  # margins equal to the vertical dividers
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]